# If $a,b \in \Bbb R$, prove that $|ab| \le (a^2+b^2)/2$

Tags: analysis

So far I have the first case when $a=b$:
\begin{align*}
|ab|
&= |b^2|\\
&=|b|^2\\
&=\frac{2|b|^2}2\\
&=\frac{b^2+b^2}2\\
&=\frac{a^2+b^2}2
\end{align*}

Case 2: $a>b$

Case 3 $a<b$

I've been stuck on this problem for a few hours now and don't know how to proceed. Am I approaching it wrong? Should I not be thinking about the cases of $a$ in terms of $b$? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $ab\ge0$ then $|ab|=ab\le ab+\dfrac{(a-b)^2}2=\dfrac{a^2+b^2}2$.
If $ab\le0$ then $|ab|=-ab\le-ab+\dfrac{(a+b)^2}2=\dfrac{a^2+b^2}2$.

Comment: this is the format my professor would prefer. starting at the premise and ending with the conclusion with all cases included.

Answer (score 6):

Without loss of generality we may assume that $a,b\ge 0$. Rewrite the inequality as $2ab\le a^2+b^2$, and then as $(a-b)^2\ge 0$.

Or else, **start** from the obvious fact that $(|a|-|b|)^2\ge 0$. Expanding, rewrite this as $2|ab|\le a^2+b^2$, and it's almost over.

Comment: the second part makes the most sense. the first part assumes that the inequality is true already. Thank you for the help. it was a life saver

Comment: You are welcome. For the first argument, one one write (for non-negative $a,b$) that $ab\le \frac{1}{2}(a^2+b^2)$ **if and only if** $2ab\le a^2+b^2$ if and only if $(a-b)^2\ge 0$. A lot of inequalities ultimately come down to the fact that a square is always non-negative.